# Assert number of elements using constraint

Tags: c#, nunit

What is the correct way of asserting the number of elements in collection using [constraint syntax](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionConstraints&r=2.6.4)?

Something like:

`Assert.That(collection, Has.Exactly(3).Elements);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the equivalent using constraint syntax

Assert.That(collection, Has.Count.EqualTo(3));

Answer (score 1):

The way you would do that is like this :

```
Assert.AreEqual(YourCollection.Count,Number);
```

Comment: The question wast about constraint syntaxt

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: Using `Assert.That` instead of `Assert.AreEqual`. I also dont want to use `collection.Count` in the first part of assert

Comment: @user963935 - You need to include more information in your question as to *why* using count isn't a valid option.. The pseudo code you have used I would imagine would use it internally too

Comment: I want to have it in a bdd way, to be consistent with other collection asserts: [nunit spec](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionConstraints&r=2.6.4)